# Max method in Collections class

Tags: java, generics, collections

I was going through the Collections class and found this method `max`. From the method signature, I understand that we can only pass the collection of those classes which implement Comparable interface of the same type or its parent classes.

```java
public static <T extends Object & Comparable<? super T>> T max(Collection<? extends T> coll)
```

But what I don't get is this:

```java
Collection<? extends T> coll
```

From my understanding, this means that we can pass collection of any type which has implemented `Comparable` interface (of the same type or it's superclasses) or its child classes. If parent has satisfied this criteria, does it not mean that all the child classes have also satisfied the same criteria?
Why can't it be just

```java
public static <T extends Object & Comparable<? super T>> T max(Collection<T> coll)
```

Is it written like this so that elements cannot be added to the coll object inside this method?

Comment: When to use `<? extends T>` or `<? super T>` is quite well expained [here](https://dzone.com/articles/covariance-and-contravariance).

Comment: `Collection<? extends T> coll` may be useful for the other overload of that method. For this one, there's no practical value. Assuming `B` extends `A` (and `A` implements `Comparable<A>`), you can infer `T` to `A`, but pass in a collection of `B` objects: `Collections.<A>max(listOfB);`, but this is pretty much useless, `Collection<T>` will work just as well.